# How to make the dropdown menu to expand when I hover it

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am customizing a Wordpress theme in localhost, my problem is the dropdown menu has to be clicked to expand/collapse, here is a site using this theme: http://mor10.com (you can test the nav menu to see what I am talking about).
 I need to make the dropdown menu expand/collapse when hovering and focusing but I am really a noob with jquery, here is the code of the dropdown menu:

```
// Add menu items with submenus to aria-haspopup="true".
container.find( '.menu-item-has-children' ).attr( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );
container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
        var _this            = $( this ),
            screenReaderSpan = _this.find( '.screen-reader-text' );

        e.preventDefault();
        _this.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
        _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

        // jscs:disable
        _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) ===     'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
        // jscs:enable
        screenReaderSpan.text( screenReaderSpan.text() === screenReaderText.expand ? screenReaderText.collapse : screenReaderText.expand );
    } );
}
initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the elements in chrome you will see that when you click on the drop down a class toggle-on is added to the button class so you may wanna try this snippet in your js file.

```
$("button.dropdown-toggle").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle-on");
    });
```

and check if it works

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: When I replace click with hover in container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) , the submenu displays when I hover the parent menu arrow, but disappears when I stop hovering it and try to select a submenu

Comment: ohhh actually i saw this now but the ul with class sub-menu also gets a toggled-on class

Comment: Thanks, what code should I add exactly ? I am really a noob with Jquery.

Comment: I think than we will have to select the entire parent element for the hover and you may wanna replace button.dropdown-toggle with menu-item-has-children and add another line after $(this).toggleClass("toggle-on"); which will be $(ul.sub-menu).toggleClass("toggled-on");

Comment: No changes either :(